# Is it necessary in a @Configuration class to autowire an @Bean for use in that class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

In a class with the `@Configuration` annotation, that has a method with the `@Bean` annotation, is it necessary to have an `@Autowired` field of the same name as the bean in order to use it within this same class?  Since the configuration class created the bean, should it not have immediate access to it by calling the method directly?

Eg:

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigClass
{
    @Autowired
    private BeanForSomething beanForSomething;

    @Bean
    public BeanForSomething beanForSomething()
    {
        return new BeanForSomething();
    }

    private void methodThatUsesBean()
    {
        beanForSomething.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Is it not possible to leave out the `@Autowired` field and just call `beanForSomething().doSomething();` to use the bean?  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the usage of the `@Bean` annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the `@Bean` declaration already takes care of that. You just need to call `beanForSomething()` in `methodThatUsesBean()`

Comment: Why is that? I'd think this would create two different instances. Is this somewhere mentioned in the Spring docs?

Answer (score 0):

As previous answerer said, you can use

```
private void methodThatUsesBean()
{
    beanForSomething().doSomething();
}
```

But in case of another bean creating you can use method parameter

```
@Bean
public BeanForSomething beanForSomething()
{
    return new BeanForSomething();
}

@Bean
public SecondBean secondBean(BeanForSomething beanForSomething)
{
     return new SecondBean(beanForSomething);
}
```